# How to convert the values of all fields in data frame from decimal to integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, integer

We have a data frame of  1.1 Million rows X 4300 Columns. The data frame contains different floating values in different columns , example of one of the field value is 0.567. In order to read the complete data frame, with all the floating values, we need considerable amount of memory. So we are thinking to read the complete dataframe by converting all the values to the integer, by multiplying /scaling the values by 1000.

So could anyone guide us?

Comment: you've not specified where the data is coming from, generally you'd want to get the data into the right datatype as early as possible.  e.g. loading and then converting will likely result in two copies of the data in memory, making things even worse.  I've assumed CSV format in my answer, but should be relatively easy to adjust

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.mul()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) to multiply the columns in dataframe, and then cast to [nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) (which supports also null values as integer type. Otherwise, if a column contains `NaN` the whole column will be treated as decimal `float` type even other values are of `int` type and have no decimal points):

```
df = df.mul(1000).astype('Int64')
```

If your dataframe does not contains `NaN` or other null values, you can simply use:

```
df = df.mul(1000).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into reading the data in "chunks", e.g.:

```
with pd.read_csv("data.csv", chunksize=1000) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        process(chunk)
```

that way you only need to keep ~4 million values in memory at one time, rather than ~5 billion. See the [IO section of the user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) for more details.

Another option would be to ensure they're loaded into [32bit floats](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.float32) (rather than 64bit floats as they are by default) when loading the data, e.g. by passing an appropriate via [`dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).  But this only halves the memory requirement, using scaled 16bit integer values (or even `float16`) might help, but again you're not going to save nearly as much memory compared to using chunked loading.